# Make USB writer protected EXCEPT one folder

Tags: usb, write-protect, user-folders

Help Please tell me solution
How to make USB write protected EXCEPT one folder
I want to make my disk write writer protected but i want to allow only 1 folder for edit modify or delete Please |Help|

Comment: And you want this to work across multiple machines? Not likely unless you use some third party tooling. In that case, add the operating systems this is supposed to work on. It would also be helpful if you add the filesystem you're using on the USB key.

Comment: What you want is theoretically impossible. Operating system has full controll over external drives, so it will always be possible to delete or modify any file on the external medium no matter what protections you create on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make your other files and folders READ ONLY.

Select all the files you want to be read-only
Right-click in the context menu and go down to properties
In the general tab click the Read-only (Only applies to files in folder)

or if you have Cygwin installed execute chmod 333 on the directory (chmod 333 your directory).  This, of course, would make the directories and files under it read-only.  So obviously you would want the execute this on the directories where you would want limited access to.